# Tokens to SMS Messages

Tags: sms

Can you add tokens to SMS messages? We want to send a link to a form to see if users want to opt in to our SMS messages, but we would like to send a link similar to a website link in an email with the checksum token. Is this possible through Civi SMS?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could use tokens in sms messages.

Be aware an issue with the required character length on sms, and the fact that tokens would represent different character lengths.

Comment: Like Flying says - and I'd recommend using URL shortening codes shuch as bitly or linkmeto.it